# Chrome behaves differently when pressing reload v pressing enter in URL field

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Was just trying to cobble a quick site together as a favour for my sister. It's based on a template she bought and I've just quickly bunged her copy/pictures in, so I'm aware the markup is far from perfect. That said, I can't see how it would be causing the following issue...

The template uses a jQuery plugin called jScrollPane to make the content sections scrollable. Sometimes however, in Chrome (v20) this doesn't work - it doesn't let you scroll all the way down.

What's really odd though, is the pattern I've found that seems to effect whether it works or not. Try the following

- Go to http://mattandkate2012.co.uk in Google Chrome - click 'Ceremony' - can you scroll down far enough to see the map? I can't.
- Press the reload icon, click 'Ceremony' - can you scroll down? I can't.
- Select the URL in the browser URL bar, press enter - can you scroll down? I can now!

Does everyone else get the same results as above, and do you have any idea why pressing enter in the URL bar has a different effect to the reload button?

This functionality works fine in Firefox and even IE!

Thanks

Pete

Comment: Confirming that I get the same behaviour as you see with Chromium 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04. I have no explanation though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a very quick look I guess it's because the section contains an image and you aren't re-initialising jScrollPane once the image loads. See:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/image.html

The difference between refreshing and pressing enter in the location bar is that the cached image is shown when you press enter in the location bar...

Comment: Thanks vitch, that seems to have done it! Interesting that the location bar uses the cache but pressing reload doesn't. Not sure what the logic behind that is.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the call to `$('.content').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});` to inside the `$(document).ready` block - if you call it before the document is ready often images or other elements won't have loaded and so the height of the containers will be wrong.